# Is it a good approach to use regular hosting package for desktop application and use api calls?

Tags: php, mysql, desktop-application, web-hosting

I am working on a desktop application using electron. I would like to store data(mysql) and images(server) online.I come from php and mysql background, My current understanding of the whole project is to purchase a web hosting package , and use php to create api calls for data transfer. However purchasing a hosting package will require me to register a domain.

My first question is:

1. some hosting providers like godaddy claims that they might block my hosting if I use it only for file storage, so this leads to question 2.
2. Is there hosting services where I can only purchase the server and mysql only without the domain? what if people want to only create api services but not the front end and only use ip address of the server instead of a domain to connect.

Please advice, thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. No, they wont block you. Feel free to use their storage only. But if you dont register any domain name, then you wont be able to browse your site. Or you can temporary visit your site by using temporary URL.
2. Many hosting providers provide this. If you want to use IP address, then you need to purchase static IP.

Answer (score 0):

You can use services such as Amazon Web Services to create your hosting instance on an elastic IP, Or have a Dedicated Server from service providers such as Liquidweb, 1and1 etc.

Having an Dedicated IP is must to run such applications, I wonder shared hosting packages provides you flexibility to access the mysql remotely.

You can always use their helpdesk for such queries.